# Removing element from hasMany association is not working

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Calling `ArrayList#remove()` or `ArrayList#removeAll()` is not working. Why could that be?

```
class Category {
    static hasMany = [elems: Elem]
    // ..
}

class Elem {
    static belongsTo = Category
    // ..
}

// ExampleController.groovy
def saveCategory(/* args */) {
    def category = categoryService.get.. // get some category object
    def elem = elemService.getElem(1)    // get some element that's in the category
    category.elems.remove(elem)  // *How to get this working*? Returns false as the object is not getting removed.
    category = categoryService.saveCategory(category)
    JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Category) {
        def map = [:]
        map['id'] = it.id
        map['elems'] = it.elems
        return map
    }
    JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Elem) {
        def map = [:]
        map['id'] = it.id
        return map
    }
    render(['category': category] as JSON)
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: you want to try http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/removeFrom.html

Comment: is this a typo?  ``Category`` vs ``PatientCategory``?  might as well be a thrid class involved, but still is confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the official way to handle this is to use the `addTo*` and `removeFrom*` methods.  you might want to look into the way, they are handling this.

http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/addTo.html

http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/removeFrom.html

Comment: No effect. Getting a copy of the collection and iterating on it and removing it the old school way and then assigning it back to the `category` object seems to work.

Comment: just to be save: after the ``removeFromElems`` you called ``category.save()``?

Comment: Yes `save` method is called. I expect the `removeFromElems` as mentioned in the docs to work, but this might be some weird anomaly.

Comment: just to be here on the save side too: how do you determine, that the elem got removed?  also i would asume, that ``removeFrom*`` with an unknown element might just ignore your wish silently.

Comment: I send the final object back to client as JSON. Added it in code example. The element is known and the id is actually send in from the client as an argument to the func.

Comment: in your original code with just the remove i would say, that elem in the list and the elem returned from the service is just another one.  so maybe you are tripping over different identities of something that seems the same object to you. as the elem is supposed to be in the category, why not just take this elem (instead of asking the service). e.g. ``def elem = category.elems.find{ it.id==1 }; if (elem) { ... category.removeFromElems(elem); ... }``

Answer (score 0):

are you saving the `category` instance afterwards?

```
category.elems.remove(elem)
category.save()
```

Comment: Of course, by calling a service method which does `category.save(flush: true)`.

Comment: are you sure that the `elem` gets removed from the collection? print the `elems` before and after deletion